# Runas command erroring on "requires elevation"

Tags: batch-file, command, installation, runas

Running basic one liner batch file, however getting error, can anyone shed some light?

```
@echo off
runas /user:Domain\jack.thompson "\\MainServer\Shared Drives\Company Share\ProgramFolder\npp.7.6.Installer.exe"
cmd /k
```

> 740: The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: I strongly doubt that user `jack.thompson` is an elevated user...

Comment: Apologies, I should have ensured I stated that I am a full access administrator across the domain and local workstation. Therefore my user details in the batch file should be fine and I am running the .bat as administrator just encase.

Comment: This problem is related to the [`runas` _command_](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) and have no relation to the `batch-file` tag. Even the question title have no sense...

Comment: @Aacini, I have changed the question and changed the tags. Thanks for your help...